# why the form is submitted by the SelectOneMenu instead of the submit button

Tags: jsf, primefaces

my pb is that when I select an item to display items in the second selectOneMenu () the submit button does not work.
at the second click the button tries to submit the form but (this action emptie the second SOM) as the second SelectOneMenu becomes empty its trigger a validation error.
primefaces 6.1
jsf2.2
tomcat8.5

```
  <h:form id="create_intervention_form">
  <h:messages id="errorMessages" style="color:red;margin:8px;" />
<h:panelGroup id="addProjet2" rendered="true">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><h:outputLabel value="Structure à visiter:" for="Client2">
                    </h:outputLabel></td>
                    <td><p:selectOneMenu id="Client2"
                            value="#{creerintervention.selected_client}" effect="fade"
                            style="width:100px" filter="true" filterMatchMode="startsWith">
                            <f:selectItems value="#{creerintervention.list_client}" var="cl"
                                itemValue="#{cl}" itemLabel="#{cl.nom_client}" />
                            <f:converter converterId="ClientConverter" />
                            <p:ajax update="create_intervention_form:station1_client"
                                listener="#{creerintervention.getStructureByClient}"
                                process="Client2" />
                        </p:selectOneMenu> <p:selectOneMenu id="station1_client"
                            value="#{creerintervention.selectedStation}" style="width:100px"
                            filter="true" filterMatchMode="startsWith">
                            <f:selectItems value="#{creerintervention.list_Station}"
                                var="entry1" itemValue="#{entry1}" itemLabel="#{entry1.nom_stat}" />
                            <f:converter converterId="StationConverter" />
                            <p:ajax partialSubmit="false" />
                        </p:selectOneMenu></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>

                    <p:commandButton value="Valider" pdate="create_intervention_form"
                        id="valide" actionListener="#{creerintervention.addOdm}"
                        styleClass="ui-priority-primary" />
                </tr>
            </table>
        </h:panelGroup>
    </h:form>
```

**ManagedBean**

```
    @RequestScoped
    @Management(name = "creerintervention")
    public class CreerIntervention {
    private String matricule;
    private agentService agentservice = new agentServiceImpl();
    private usersService usersService = new usersServiceImpl();
    private clientService clientService = new clientServiceImpl();
    private List<client> list_client;
    private List<station> list_Station;
    private List<SelectItem> clientList;
    //private Map<String, String> clientList;
    //private Map<String, String> StationList;
    private List<SelectItem> StationList;
    private station selectedStation;
    private client  Selected_client;
    {
           //*** initialiser la liste des client dans le SelectOnMenu
          list_client = clientService.findAll();
    }

    public void getStructureByClient()  
    {      
            // ######## Préparer la liste des nom des clients  ######## //
            list_Station=stationService.findByRefClient(getSelected_client().getRef());
            log.info("La refernce du client est ---"+ Selected_client.getRef());
            log.info("LES STIONS SONT D UN NBR DE  ---"+ list_Station.size());

    }
    public void addOdm(ActionEvent e)
    {    

    log.info("Matricule:" + matricule) ;
    log.info("destination:" +destination); 
    log.info("client:"+Selected_client.getNom_client()) ;
    log.info("station:"+ selectedStation.getNom_stat());
    log.info("objet mission:"+ obj_mission );
    log.info("date depart:"+  date_dep );
    log.info("date ret:"+  date_retour );
    log.info("moyen transp:"+  moyen_transport) ;
    log.info("imma:"+  immatriculation) ;
    log.info("prise en charge :"+  prise_en_charge) ;
    log.info("struct:"+  structure) ;

    }
    .....
    Setters and Getters...
```

Comment: any answers please ? this problem makes me crazy

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25339056/understanding-primefaces-process-update-and-jsf-fajax-execute-render-attributes

Comment: thank you Kukeltje for the excelent link;

Comment: You can filter all JSF questions and sort by 'votes', read all with more than 40 upvotes (Q or A) Always good to know at least their existence when you run into issues... Cheers

Comment: thank you Kukeltje for the excelent link; however  after understanding the process and update I understand why the submit does not work.
the value of the second selectOneMenu triggers a validation error
as if it is null
(the items from the first selectOnMenu are generated in the postconstract)
please I really need your help because I blocked on this point for several days

Comment: Then don't 'process' that second value... Now you you know what needs to be done, you can search for that in google

Comment: I have progressed ; by changing the scope of the bean to Sessionscoped the problem seems to be fixed; is there any way to keep the bean in RequestScopped and the value of the second selectoneMenu

Comment: im realy in a deadlock situation  please help !!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have get the solution ; the problem was in the Scope the right one is @ViewScoped.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
<h:head>
<title>Insert title here</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
     <h:form id="create_intervention_form">
        <h:messages id="errorMessages" style="color:red;margin:8px;" />
        <table>
        <tr>
            <td><p:outputLabel value="Matricule:" for="Matricule" /></td>
            <td><p:inputText id="Matricule"
                value="#{teststation.matricule}" size="5" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><h:outputLabel value="Structure à visiter:" for="Client2"></h:outputLabel> </td>
             <td>  
                <p:panel id="st">

                <p:selectOneMenu  id="Client2"  value="#{teststation.selected_client}">
                <f:selectItems value="#{teststation.list_client}" var="cl" itemValue="#{cl}" itemLabel="#{cl.nom_client}" />
                <f:converter converterId="ClientConverter" />
                <p:ajax  update="station1_client" listener ="#{teststation.getStructureByClient}" />
                </p:selectOneMenu> 
                <p:selectOneMenu id="station1_client"  value="#{teststation.selectedStation}" >
                <f:attribute name="selected_station" value="#{teststation.selectedStation}" />
                <f:selectItems value="#{teststation.list_Station}" var="entry1" itemValue="#{entry1}" itemLabel="#{entry1.nom_stat}" />
                 <f:converter converterId="StationConverter" />

                </p:selectOneMenu>
                </p:panel>
            </td>
        </tr>
                <tr>
                <td><h:outputLabel value="Immatriculation:" for="imma"></h:outputLabel> </td>
                <td><p:inputText size="20"  value="#{teststation.immatriculation}" id="imma"></p:inputText></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <p:growl id="growl" life="2000" />
                <td></td>
                <td><p:commandButton value="Valider"  id="valide"  update="errorMessages"   actionListener="#{teststation.addOdm}" styleClass="ui-priority-primary" /> 
                </td>
                </tr>

                    </table>

            </h:form>

</h:body>
</html>
```

the ManagedBean

```
@ViewScoped
@ManagedBean(name = "teststation")
public class TestStation {
    private String matricule;
    private stationService stationService = new stationServiceImpl();
    private clientService clientService = new clientServiceImpl();
    public static Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(CreerIntervention.class.getName());
    private String nom;
    private String client_name;
    private List<client> list_client;
    private List<station> list_Station;
    private List<SelectItem> clientList;
    //private Map<String, String> clientList;
    //private Map<String, String> stationList;
    private List<SelectItem> stationList;
    private String immatriculation;
    private String ref_Selected_client;
    private String Nom_Selected_client;
    private String ref_Selected_station;
    private String Nom_Selected_station;
    private List<station> station;
    private station selectedStation;
    private client  Selected_client;
    FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    HttpSession session = (HttpSession) fc.getExternalContext().getSession(false);
    Map<String, String> selectedStationParam= fc.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();

    @PostConstruct
    public void initMyBean() 
        {
        log.info("ici PosteConstract"+this.getClass().hashCode());

         }

    public TestStation() 
    {
        super();
        log.info("ici Constract  "+this.getClass().hashCode());

    }
    {
          list_client = clientService.findAll();

    }
    public void updateSelectedStation()  
    {    

        log.info("LES updateSelectedStatio  ---"+ list_Station.get(0).getNom_stat());
    }
    public void getStructureByClient()  
    {       
            log.info("La refernce du client selectioné est ---   "+ Selected_client.getRef());
            list_Station=stationService.findByRefClient(getSelected_client().getRef());
            stationList= new ArrayList<>();
            for (station o : list_Station) 
            {
                stationList.add(new SelectItem(o.getNom_stat(),o.getRef_stat()));
            } 

            log.info("LES STIONS SONT D UN NBR DE  ---"+ list_Station.get(0).getNom_stat());


    }
    public void addOdm()
    {    Nom_Selected_station=selectedStation.getNom_stat();
            //log.info("num_odm :" + num_odm) ;
    log.info("Matricule:" + matricule) ;
    log.info("client:"+Selected_client.getNom_client()) ;
    log.info("station:"+ Nom_Selected_station);
    log.info("imma:"+  immatriculation) ;
    }




    public void addMessage(String summary) {
        FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, summary,  null);
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, message);
    }
    public void cancelAction(ActionEvent e)
    {  
        log.info("etat valeur ShowForm555 = ");


    }


    public String getMatricule() {
        return matricule;
    }

    public void setMatricule(String matricule) {
        this.matricule = matricule;
    }



    public String getNom() {
        return nom;
    }

    public void setNom(String nom) {
        this.nom = nom;
    }



    public String getNom_Selected_client() {
        return Nom_Selected_client;
    }

    public void setNom_Selected_client(String nom_Selected_client) {
        Nom_Selected_client = nom_Selected_client;
    }

    public String getRef_Selected_client() {
        return ref_Selected_client;
    }

    public void setRef_Selected_client(String Ref_Selected_client) {
        this.ref_Selected_client = Ref_Selected_client;
    }


    public String getClient_name() {
        return client_name;
    }

    public void setClient_name(String client_name) {
        this.client_name = client_name;
    }



    /*public Map<String, String> getClientList() {
        return clientList;
    }

    public void setClientList(Map<String, String> clientList) {
        this.clientList = clientList;
    }

    public List<client> getList_client() {
        return list_client;
    }

    public void setList_client(List<client> list_client) {
        this.list_client = list_client;
    }*/



    public String getImmatriculation() {
        return immatriculation;
    }

    public void setImmatriculation(String immatriculation) {
        this.immatriculation = immatriculation;
    }

    public List<station> getStation() {
        return station;
    }

    public void setStation(List<station> station) {
        this.station = station;
    }

    /*public List<station> getList_Station() {
        return list_Station;
    }

    public void setList_Station(List<station> list_Station) {
        this.list_Station = list_Station;
    }*/

    /*public Map<String, String> getStationList() {
        return stationList;
    }

    public void setStationList(Map<String, String> stationList) {
        stationList = stationList;
    }*/

    public void setClientList(List<SelectItem> clientList) {
        this.clientList = clientList;
    }

    public List<SelectItem> getStationList() {
        return stationList;
    }

    public void setStationList(List<SelectItem> stationList) {
        this.stationList = stationList;
    }

    public List<SelectItem> getClientList() {
        return clientList;
    }


    public station getSelectedStation() {
        return selectedStation;
    }

    public void setSelectedStation(station selectedStation) {
        this.selectedStation = selectedStation;
    }

    public client getSelected_client() {
        return Selected_client;
    }

    public void setSelected_client(client selected_client) {
        Selected_client = selected_client;
    }

    public List<client> getList_client() {
        return list_client;
    }

    public void setList_client(List<client> list_client) {
        this.list_client = list_client;
    }

    public List<station> getList_Station() {
        return list_Station;
    }

    public void setList_Station(List<station> list_Station) {
        this.list_Station = list_Station;
    }
    public String getRef_Selected_station() {
        return ref_Selected_station;
    }
    public void setRef_Selected_station(String ref_Selected_station) {
        this.ref_Selected_station = ref_Selected_station;
    }
    public String getNom_Selected_station() {
        return Nom_Selected_station;
    }
    public void setNom_Selected_station(String nom_Selected_station) {
        Nom_Selected_station = nom_Selected_station;
    }

}
```

the StationConverter

```
@FacesConverter("StationConverter")
public class StationConverter implements Converter {

    public static Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(StationConverter.class.getName());
    stationService    statServ = new stationServiceImpl();
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String submittedValue) {
        if (submittedValue == null || submittedValue.isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        }

        try {
            log.info("4- submitted value for Station Converter  **********   "+submittedValue);
            log.info("5- returned Object for Station Converter  **********   "+statServ.findByRef(submittedValue).getNom_stat());
            return statServ.findByRef(submittedValue);

        } catch (NumberFormatException exception) {
            throw new ConverterException(new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Conversion Error", "Not a valid Client ID"));
        }}
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object modelValue) {
        if (modelValue == null) {
            return "";
        }
        log.info(modelValue.getClass());
       if (modelValue instanceof station ) {
           log.info( "6- la valeur en String Converter Station  est ****** "+String.valueOf(((station) modelValue).getNom_stat()));
            return String.valueOf(((station) modelValue).getRef_stat());
        } else {
             throw new ConverterException(new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Conversion Error", "Not a valid Station instance"));
         } 
    }    
}
```